# How to access a drawer layout in all the activities of my android app?

Tags: android, tabs, navigation-drawer

I am developing a quiz app which consists of drawer layout in all the activities.The contents in the drawer is same and i want it in all the activities.By searching google i found a solution that declaring drawer in one activity and inherit in all the activities,it works well too.I am attaching the code below.
Now the problem is that i need Tab in one of by activity so i don't know how to inherit 2 activity in here[which is not possible].
Can any one help me out with this problem?

Simply saying,
I have a option that i can extend only i class what to do if i want two classes?

DrawActivity.java

```
public void onCreateDrawer() {

    // R.id.drawer_layout should be in every activity with exactly the same id.
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(DrawActivity.this,drawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer2,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name)
    {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
        {
            getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
        {
            getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    //getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    if (settings.getString("logged","").toString().equals("logged")) {
        layers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.layers_array1);
        flag=0;
    }
    else {
        layers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.layers_array);
        flag=1;
    }

    drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,layers));
    drawerList.setSelector(R.color.darkgreen);
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
            selectItemFromDrawer(pos);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: You can create a MAIN_ACTIVITY with a drawer and use fragments inside it.

Comment: Is it possible only in fragment?